# How do I create an html code with a string on python to render on django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

In my views:

```
post_image = '<div class="images slides"></div>'
```

console.log(document.body):

```
<body>
    "<div class="images slides"</div>"
</body>
```

What I want:

```
<body>
    <div class="images slides"</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render the content as HTML, use the safe filter

```
<div>
    {{ post_image|safe }}
</div>
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#safe